# Unit testing asynchronous call in angular

Tags: angular-test

I have following function in a service 'MyService':

```
myFunction(input: MyInput){
this.someService.someFunction(<any> input).then(result => {
  console.log('Somefunction worked successfully');
  return result;
}).catch(reason => {
  throw new Error('Somefunction failed');
})
}
```

And unit test for myFunction is as:

```
// create test data
spyOn(someService, 'someFunction').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(dummyResult));

// invoke target unit
const response = myService.myFunction(dummyInput);

// validations
expect(someService.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(someService.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(someService.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dummyInput);
expect(response).toBe(dummyResult)
```

First three validations pass, but last one doesn't as call to someFunction is asynchronous and hence response is still undefined at time of validation.

How to handle such scenario? 
I came across fakeAsync but examples are a bit different from this.